# Imgur block my IP?

Tags: imgur

I upload 12 image to imgur every half hour.

But meet this issue.

> Imgur ERROR message: {'exception': [], 'code': 429, 'type':
>   'ImgurException', 'message': 'You are uploading too fast. Please wait
>   -0 more minutes.'}

I don't understand why is -0 minutes. I guess I reach my rate limit, so try to see my rate limit. But it look normal.

```
{
    "data": {
        "UserLimit": 2000,
        "UserRemaining": 2000,
        "UserReset": 1521378886,
        "ClientLimit": 12500,
        "ClientRemaining": 12500
    },
    "success": true,
    "status": 200
}
```

I try in different machine in same CLIENTID, the upload function work fine.

Did my IP be banned by imgur? When will they free my IP?

UPDATE:

I find out each IP imgur will treat different user.
But my machine curl credits api. The response look fine.

```
curl --request GET \                                                                                                        
--url 'https://api.imgur.com/3/credits' \
--header 'Authorization: Client-ID xxx'

{"data":{"UserLimit":500,"UserRemaining":497,"UserReset":1521394842,"ClientLimit":12500,"ClientRemaining":12457},"success":true,"status":200}⏎
```

When I run upload image. It still will show

> Imgur ERROR message: {'message': 'You are uploading too fast. Please
>   wait -0 more minutes.', 'type': 'ImgurException', 'code': 429,
>   'exception': []}

However, other image function work fine such as get image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently "[there is an upload limit of 50 images per IP address per hour](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-What-is-the-size-limit-)".

I don't know why they don't state this on the main [api.imgur.com](https://api.imgur.com/#limits) page, it's essential information for an API...

Comment: I'm uploading around 10 images a day. At the end of the month my servers IP run into "Rate-limit exceeded!". I guess that there are some limits they don't mention. Locally upload works with same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but, it was not related to my IP.

I checked the file extension and it was a `.heic` file extension - which is not valid for Imgur.

After checking the [source](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9lmsqw/upload_to_imgur_file_type_invalid_1_error/), I saved the image to a valid file extension - in my case, to `.png`.

By changing the file extension to a valid one, I was able to upload the image.

Source: [Upload to Imgur "File type invalid (1)" error](https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/9lmsqw/upload_to_imgur_file_type_invalid_1_error/) on Reddit.