# Error code 429 Too many request, but I still have credits

Tags: node.js, imgur

I have a script that upload 3-5 images per day, but I woke up today with an error code 429 Too many request. After checking my credits I still have basically everything.

```
{
"data": {
    "UserLimit": 500,
    "UserRemaining": 500,
    "UserReset": 1613816368,
    "ClientLimit": 12500,
    "ClientRemaining": 12500
},
"success": true,
"status": 200
}
```

This script has been running for almost a year without problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Imgur block my IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49347872/imgur-block-my-ip)

Comment: Also asked, without answer, in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62790438/imgur-api-error-429-when-uploading-images https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57908261/imgur-api-all-requests-failing-with-429-unknown-this-is-their-code-for-over-ra https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60776228/imgur-api-bug-too-many-requests-by-image-upload https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55417370/imgur-api-getting-too-many-request-error-even-though-x-ratelimit-userremain

Comment: No. One of the answer is: "there is an upload limit of 50 images per IP address per hour", but I upload less than 50 images per hour.

Comment: @Joey Use proxy, Luke